# TeamCity: Snapshot dependency not triggering as expected

Tags: teamcity

Here's the scenario: I have a TeamCity "master" build that aggregates the results of 7 other builds.

I'm using snapshot dependencies, as the TeamCity documentation suggests, to achieve this:

[image]

[image]

However, something odd happened today.  Functional Tests 5 failed, as it sometimes does, and re-queued itself automatically (all 7 dependent builds have a Retry Build Trigger), and it then succeeded. However, the "master" build configuration didn't re-trigger or otherwise recognize that Functional Tests 5 eventually passed.

[image]

Is this a bug in TC or have I somehow mis-configured the master build

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour can be due to [this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-31232). You are welcome to watch/ vote for it.
The workaround that can help is adding a [Finish Build Trigger](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+Finish+Build+Trigger) to the Functional Tests build configuration that will trigger the master build. As long as there are no pending changes, the other Functional Tests builds should not be triggered

Comment: Oleg, just to be sure I'm clear on the workaround.  You're suggesting I add a Finish Build Trigger to the Functional Tests (Master) that itself references Functional Tests?  A kind of recursive Finish Build Trigger?

Comment: You can select 'Do not run new build if there is a suitable one' in snapshot dependency options - in this case there will be no triggering of snapshot dependencies without incoming changes